# AngularJS ng-disabled directive with expression is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

User Story: When a new user clicks the New User checkbox and accepts the TermsAndConditions radio button, the Register button should be enabled.

My code in angularJS isn't working. The Register button remains disabled. Wondering what went wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div>
        <label>New User?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isNewUser"/>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="isNewUser">
        <label>Accept Terms and Conditions</label>
        <input type="radio" value="yes" name="tnc" ng-model="tnc"/><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" value="no" name="tnc" ng-model="tnc" /><label>No</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="isNewUser" >
        <input type="submit" value="Register" ng-show="isNewUser" ng-disabled="hasAcceptedTnC('{{tnc}}')">
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">
var LoginCtrl = function ($scope) {
        $scope.isNewUser = false;
        $scope.tnc = "no";

        $scope.hasAcceptedTnC = function(value) {
            //alert(value);
            return "yes"==value;
        };
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure to to add the 'required' on input tag on which you want to make decision.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `ng-disabled` expression is evaluated in the present scope. Hence, you should only need the following without any extra interpolation with `{{..}}`:

```
    <input type="submit" 
           value="Register" 
           ng-show="isNewUser" 
           ng-disabled="!hasAcceptedTnC(tnc)">
```

Note that I added a `!` since you probably want the button disabled if the user has *not* accepted the TnC.

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/95UiO4Rd2IMh8T1KjSQK?p=preview

---

A comment was posted below asking how to reason about when to use `{{...}}` and when to use bare expression with a given `ng-*` directive. Unfortunately, there is no syntactical clue hidden in the directives which can reveal that information. Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) will turn out to be fastest way to find out this information.

Comment: that mean if the boolean variable used in ng-disabled is in parent scope, wont work is it?

Comment: @KuganKumar It will unless there is an `isolated` scope directive in between. Values defined on the scope (while being read, at least) are inherited seamlessly to any child scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($scope.Data.length > 0)
  $scope.isNewUser = true;
else $scope.isNewUser = false;
```

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" 
            ng-click="Search()" 
            ng-disabled="!isNewUser" 
            aria-label="pause">Assign </md-button>
```

Answer (score -11):

I tried taking help from the above solution but it didn't work. So I found another solution. By adding the following code in the CSS for that element, solves my problem
     pointer-events: none;

So in general :-

```
 element[disabled]{
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Comment: This goes against the concept of ng-disabled handing this much better for you.