# Why is ng-disabled not working on button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4MkenJPczFbxy5aoillL?p=preview

[image]

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">

<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<p>Button should not be disabled:</p>

<div ng-init="main.btnDisabled = false">
    <button ng-model="main.my_button"
         ng-class="{ 'btn-success' : !tc.switching, 'btn-disabled' : tc.switching }"
         disabled="main.btnDisabled"
         type="button"
         class="btn btn-info btn-sm switch-btn">My Button</button>  
</div>
```

Angular

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  vm = this;
  vm.btnDisabled = false;
});
```

I found [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518691/angularjs-ng-disabled-directive-with-expression-is-not-working), but it didn't work in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button is disabled because there is `disabled` attribute. This is enough for browser to know that element must be inactive. The value for disabled `attribute`  doesn't matter, it can be anything.

This is exactly the reason why Angular provides [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive, which adds `disabled` attibute when expression evaluates to `true`, and removes when it's `false`.

In your case you should use

```
<button ng-model="main.my_button"
        ng-class="{ 'btn-success' : !tc.switching, 'btn-disabled' : tc.switching }"
        ng-disabled="main.btnDisabled"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-sm switch-btn">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems that I see here.

First, change disabled to ng-disabled.

Second, when you click the button nothing will change/happen. Instead of putting that functionality into your ng-class, use something like ng-click to change the state.

This isn't contributing to your problem but make sure that you include $scope before passing it into your controller function.

Speaking of $scope, the plunker would be a bit easier to read if you put something on the scope instead of using a controller alias. No problem with that, it just might help you and other people debug your code.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'll stick to ony $scope in plunkers, I prefer `as` in regular dev