# ng-disabled does not get scope object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application working good.I don't have any problem with my code. **I know 100% sure.**

But i don't know why `ng-disabled` does not working for me.

My controller having

```
$scope.userid=1;
$scope.currentuserid=1;
```

Html having

```
<input id="selfRating" tabindex="3" name="selfRating" placeholder="Rating" ng-disabled="userid == currentuserid" class="form-control"
                                        ng-model="selfRating" only-digits required />
```

Actually it's working, while I directly use the `ng-disabled="true"//or false` in `input` filed.

But it's does not working while check the condition into inside of `ng-disabled`.

`ng-disabled="userid == currentuserid"`.

Why? I hope you guys got this problem with `ng-disabled`. what was the solution?

- [I also tried **`ng-disabled="{{userid == currentuserid}}"`**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518691/angularjs-ng-disabled-directive-with-expression-is-not-working) but does not working.

Please save my time.

Thanks...

Comment: its work fine. check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/18QY1EinZqawe24Tlalo?p=preview)

Comment: Actually am using this condition inside of repeater. So is this threw any problem for me?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar . But Mins is does not working

Comment: should we look repeater ?

Comment: are you sure that you do not have name conflicts?

Comment: your use of primitives is likely the root of the problem since `ng-repeat` creates child scopes. Best practice is to use objects in scope models. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Sounds like you might have a nested scope? Try $parent.userid == $parent.currentuserid

Comment: I can't show my full code for a large code.  I don't know why my side is not working.